# jQuery: select text before a tag containing a string

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some html such as

```
<div class="abstract">Nov 12, 2009 <b>...</b> Tender and flavorful, 
<b>veal</b> cutlets are lean and quick-cooking. If <b>veal</b> 
isn't for you though, feel free to substitute chicken cutlets 
for a classic <b>...</b>
</div>
```

I would like to style that date at the beginning differently.

I think I can get that first b tag with something like

`$('.abstract b:contains("...")).css(-something-)`

But how about the text in front of this?

Answer (score 1):

I would encapsulate that text in a span of some sort, like `<div class="abstract"><span class='date-year'>Nov 12, 2009</span><b>...</b>`, then you could just go with `$(".abstract .date-year")`. If you don't have access to the page, you could get the inner text with `$(".abstract").html()`, look for the first instance of the `<b>`, and then substring it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely *cannot* change the HTML, you can do something like this:

```
$('.abstract').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && $(this).next().is('b:contains("...")');
}).first().wrap('<span>').parent().addClass('date');
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HLLDG/**

If the date is always the first text node, you can get rid of that second condition in the filter:

```
$('.abstract').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).first().wrap('<span>').parent().addClass('date');
```

Comment: This looks good.  What is the significance of the `this.nodeType ===3`?

Comment: @Steve: Text nodes have a `nodeType` of `3`. It's so that you select the first text node, not the first element.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to wrap the date in an HTML tag of some sought so that you can then apply a style rule to it, otherwise the browser has no way to know what you want styling one way, and what another.

After that you don't need any jQuery; just apply a CSS rule:

```
<div class="abstract"><span>Nov 12, 2009</span> <b>...</b> Tender and flavorful, 
<b>veal</b> cutlets are lean and quick-cooking.
```

CSS:

```
.abstract>span {
   color: red;
}
```